# Formatting text piped to lpr; adding margins

Tags: command-line

I often find it useful to print text using

```
echo 'stuff' | lpr
```

The lpr output does get hard to read whenever the text is more than small paragraphs; So I would like to add left and right margins to the text.  A simple right margin fix is

```
echo 'stuff' | fmt -w 55 | lpr
```

This however does not add any margin to the left of the text.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a `-w` option for **fmt** which sets the maximum width of a line and the `-s` option to split long lines. The default for `-w` is 75 characters. My quick solution would be something similar to this:

```
cat [stuff] | fmt -sw 50 | awk '{printf "   "$0"\n"}' | lpr
```

Here **fmt** limits the characters per line (in this example 50) and divides long lines automatically. Then this output is piped to **awk** which adds as many spaces as there are between the first quotation marks after **printf**, then puts the line from **fmt** and eventually makes a line break by `"\n"`.

I am sure that it can be done with **awk** solely, however I was so biased by your **fmt** that I kept it. I will add an EDIT as soon as I have an expression with **awk**
only.

6chars

Comment: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be marked as a code sample. You can use backticks `\`` to mark your inline code. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I ended up writing a small c++ app letting me practise argp a little. http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Argp.html#Argp